# Counting and probability

Tags: probability

How many ways are there to put the set of weights $\{2^0, 2^1, 2^2, \dotsc, 2^{n−1}\}$ on a balance, one weight after another, on either of the two pans, such that throughout the whole process of $n$ steps the left pan is never heavier than the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the largest weight outweighs all the others, so it must go on the right.  Once it is placed, there is no further constraint on placing the remaining weights.  Let $N(n)$ be the number of ways of placing the weights.  If the heavy weight is placed after $k$ other weights have been placed, you have ${n-1 \choose k}$ ways to select the weights to be placed first, $N(k)$ ways to place them, $(n-k-1)!$ ways to order the remaining weights, and $2^{n-k-1}$ ways to choose the pans.  So $$N(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}N(k)(n-k-1)!2^{n-k-1}$$  which yields $$\begin {array} &n&0&1&2&3&4&5\\N(n)&1&1&3&15&105&945 \end {array}$$  This matches [A001147](http://oeis.org/A001147), which is $(2n-1)!!$.  I don't have a proof of that last formula, but many of the cited ways to produce this sequence are related to this problem.